# Funcion max() de Python para enteros negativos

Tags: python, funciones, números-enteros

La función `max()` de Python me devuelve el número con mayor valor absoluto de una lista:

```
arr='-1 -2 -2 -3'
arr=arr.split()
m=max(arr)
print(m)
```

Este código devuelve `-3`.

Lo único que se me ha ocurrido para que devuelta el número mayor es convertir los enteros a flotantes, pero seguro que tiene que haber un sistema mejor.

```
arr='-1 -2 -2 -3'
arr=arr.split()
arr=[float(i) for i in arr]
m=max(arr)
print(int(m))
```

Este código sí que devuelve `-1`, que es realmente el mayor.

¿Existe un método más eficiente que no implique `sort()`?

Comment: en ningún momento usas `sort()`, en el primer caso te da un resultado erroneo porque estas sacando el máximo de una lista de string y en el segúndo te devuelve lo correcto por que el valor es uno numérico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error está en que preguntas por el máximo de una lista de **cadenas**, no de **enteros**.

La función `split()` divide una cadena en una lista de cadenas. La función `max` compara las cadenas alfabéticamente, por lo que "-1" < "-3".

La lista con la que trabajas es esta:

```
['-1', '-2', '-2', '-3']
```

La lista con la que quieres trabajar es esta otra:

```
[-1, -2, -2, -3]
```

La forma correcta es convertir cada elemento a entero usando `int`.

```
arr='-1 -2 -2 -3'
arr=[int(x) for x in arr.split()]
m=max(arr)
print(arr, m)
```

produce:

```
[-1, -2, -2, -3] -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Como ya ha dicho @Candid Moe, el problema es que usas un array de caracteres, que por defecto es ascii. Así que sospecho que `max()` trabaja sobre los valores numéricos de cada carácter. Sin poder confirmarlo en la [documentación: max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

si ves parte de la [tabla ascii](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dado que todos tienen `-` al comienzo están a la par, pero nótese que el `"3"` equivale a 51 así que sería mayor que `"1"`.

Una prueba rápida aunque no completa sería probando con `arr='-1 -2 -2 -3 0'` si trabajara con los valores enteros "absolutos" seguiría resultando -3, pero resulta que el resultado es `0`, posiblemente porque el valor ascii de `0` es `48` mientras el de `-` es `45`. Además, aprecia que si pones letras en la lista, python no te lanza un error de tipo de dato mal manejado.

Tendrías que asegurarte que sean valores numérico tipo `int` o `float` para que `max()` tenga sentido en contraste con los valores ascii.

Comment: Python usa Unicode internamente, y el ordenamiento entre strings se hace lexicograficamente (no hay conversión numérica).

Answer (score 1):

Max() no devuelve el número con mayor valor abosulto. Devuelve el número de mayor valor.

Lo que está pasando es que como bien dice [Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe), tu estás utilizando un formato de string. Es decir al hacer la comparación de ver cuál es mayor al otro está comparando el string, y como el primer caracter es el mismo se fija si el segundo caracter es "mayor" o "menor" en cada caso.

Aqui tienes dos opciones. Mantener la lista o pasarte a un numpy array. El caso de la lista está bien explicado e implementado por [Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe), con su "one-liner":

> arr=[int(x) for x in arr.split()]

Si quieres pasarte a numpy tienes que importar la biblioteca de numpy al inicio:

```
import numpy as np
```

y luego de obtener tus valores en la lista tranformar esa lista a un numpy array y utilizar la función max de numpy. La ventaja de este segundo método es en el caso de que necesites seguir haciendo operaciones con estos valores, ya que numpy tiene un montón de funcionalidades para trabajar con vectores y matrices.

En ese caso tendrías algo así:

```
import numpy as np

arr='-1 -2 -2 -3'
arr=arr.split()
arr=np.asarray(arr) # Esto castea a numpy array
m=np.max(arr)
print(int(m))
```

O quizás:

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.asarray([-1, -2, -2, -3])
m=np.max(arr)
print(int(m))
```

EDIT: Si prefieres especificar explícitamente que el arreglo sea de enteros basta agregarle un ".astype(int)" al array. Es decir, por ejemplo:

```
# Para el primer ejemplo
arr=np.asarray(arr).astype(int)
# Para el segundo ejemplo
arr = np.asarray([-1,-2,-2,-3]).astype(int)
# Para cualquiera de los ejemplos, pero en una línea aparte
arr = arr.astype(int)
```

Nota: Lo más lógico es que tu intérprete de python genere un array de enteros, pero en caso de que necesites castear algo que te haya quedado en float o en strings puede ser útil..

Comment: El OP no distingue entre string y entero. Proponerle usar `numpy` es el consejo que necesita en este momento.